# Torch Lua, how to compute the cosine distance for each pair of single values of two tensors?

Tags: lua, torch, cosine-similarity, trigonometry

I have the current programming problem in **Torch**.

I have a table made of two Tensors:

```
require 'nn'
N = 4
aaaTensor = torch.randn(N)
bbbTensor = torch.randn(N)
thisTable = {aaaTensor, bbbTensor}
```

I would like to compute the **cosine distance for each pair of single values** of aaaTensor and bbbTensor:

- the cosine distance between `aaaTensor[1]` and `bbbTensor[1]`
- the cosine distance between `aaaTensor[2]` and `bbbTensor[2]`
- ...
- the cosine distance between `aaaTensor[N]` and `bbbTensor[N]`

And I don't know how to do this.
If I use the `nn.CosineDistance()` module ([link](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/table.md#nn.CosineDistance)), it will compute the **general cosine distance** between aaaTensor and bbbTensor:

```
cosine = nn.CosineDistance()
cosine:forward{aaaTensor, bbbTensor}
0.7185
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 1]
```

I want to have N=4 outputs.

**How could I implement this one-by-one cosine distance computation?**
Thanks

Comment: Usually I'd expect the cosine distance to be applied to two vectors but `aaaTensor[1]` and `bbbTensor[2]` are just numbers. What is the cosine difference of two numbers supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/table.md#nn.CosineDistance) says nn.CosineDistance() accepts batches. So (although cosine distance of single values does not make sense) you can do it like;

```
require 'nn'
N = 4
aaaTensor = torch.randn(N,1)
bbbTensor = torch.randn(N,1)
thisTable = {aaaTensor, bbbTensor}
cosine = nn.CosineDistance()
cosine:forward{aaaTensor, bbbTensor}
```